# How to exit this loop?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I want to exit a loop just by pressing Enter. How to do this? Now the loop exits when I enter any nonnumeric value and press Enter. How to exit by entering nothing and pressing Enter?

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int numberIn;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter numbers!");

while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    numberIn = scan.nextInt();
    numbers.add(numberIn);
}

System.out.println("Numbers: " + numbers + ".");
```

Comment: Does `scan.next()` work for you instead of `scan.nextInt()`?

Comment: It doesn't exit the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int numberIn;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter numbers!");

String input;
while (!(input = scan.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    numberIn = Integer.parseInt(input);
    numbers.add(numberIn);
}

System.out.println("Numbers: " + numbers + ".");
```

Comment: Thanks. So there is no other way than to enter a string and convert it to integer.

Comment: I guess not, nextInt waits for an integer so you can't check if the input is empty to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try `hasNext()`:

```
while (scan.hasNext("\\d+")) {
    numberIn = scan.nextInt();
    numbers.add(numberIn);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? What happens exactly?

Comment: The same happens. The loop continues if I just press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int numberIn;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter numbers!");

String input;
while (!(input = scan.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    numberIn = Integer.parseInt(input);
    numbers.add(numberIn);
}

System.out.println("Numbers: " + numbers + ".");
```

Comment: This doesn't exit the loop.

Comment: Your answer seems very similar to mine ;)

Comment: @IsidroGH didn't even see your post. Sorry! :)